# Why can I not set Workbench Access Control fields?

Tags: 7, workbench

I am attempting to set the workbench access control fields on two content types. Under the "Access Control Fields" section of the Access settings page, my two content types can be seen. I drop down the menu and select the taxonomy that already exists on each page, which I would like to control the permissions of who can alter and publish changes on these pages.

However, every time that I set these two fields to the correct field, then hit "save," the changes are NOT saved and they still say, "No Access Control Field" on each content type. "Require a Workbench Access form element" is NOT checked.

Can anyone shed some light on why these changes would not be saving? Am I missing a setting somewhere that would be necessary for these access control fields to be valid?